# How to make a python script that downloads all images of a twitter page within a time period

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been searching for a solution for scraping all images from a twitter page within a specified time period. I haven't found any solution/tutorials online, all image scraping tutorials were made for google and modifying them for twitter didn't work for me. Does someone have a solution or a tutorial i can use to make this script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this Python Twitter API:
https://github.com/bear/python-twitter

Might be of good help!